# ¿Cómo lleno una tabla intermedia de mucho a muchos?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola estoy intentando llenar un campo extra de mi tabla intermedia

del request obtengo miss datos pero los únicos que me interesa son el "ID" y "CANTIDAD"

He intentado de esta forma.

```html
 $productos = array_column($request->all(),'id');
  $cantidad = array_column($request->all(),'cantidad');

 $nuevoPedido->productos()->sync($productos, ['cantidad' => $cantidad]);
```

si se guarda mis datos, pero el campo de cantidad en la tabla intermedia no se registra.

lo he intentado usar attach pero me dice que de que le estoy pasando una matriz y es un dato

según la documentacion de laravel.

podría usar esta forma

```html
App\User::find(1)->roles()->save($role, ['expires' => $expires]);
```

pero no funciona. Así que no se que este pasando.

en Resumen

**Necesito poner un dato más a mi tabla intermedia**

tengo mis 3 tablas

Pedido
Productos
pedidos_productos

en mi  Pedido mi relación la tengo de está manera.

```html
   public function user()
    {
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function productos()
    {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Producto::class,'pedido_productos');
    }
```

Productos

```html
   public function pedidos()
    {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Pedido::class,'pedido_productos')->withPivot('cantidad');
    }
```

pedido_productos

```html
    public function pedido()
    {
     return $this->belongstoMany(Pedido::class,'pedido_id');
    }

    public function producto()
    {
     return $this->belongstoMany(Producto::class,'producto_id');
    }
```

Comment: Para poder responderte correctamente, necesitamos ver tus modelos, que es el lugar donde inicia esta accion.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas agregar lo siguiente al crear la relacion en el modelo

```
// metodo productos()
return $this->belongsToMany(Model::class)->withPivot('cantidad');

// metodo roles()
return $this->belongsToMany(Model::class)->withPivot('expires');
```

en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships) podes buscar como usar el metodo `withPivot`

Comment: Omití poner esto en la descripción de mi pregunta. pero de igual forma lo tengo así.